# 1 month and 2 week overstay in the US

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I travelled to the US last year 3 times on the third trip the officer wrote 1 month on my passport which I did not discover until after the 1 month expired. I overstayed one month and 2 weeks. Can I be admitted into the US again? What can I do?

Comment: What is your nationality? Which kind of visa did you have, or did you use the Visa Waiver Program? What does your I-94 record say?

Comment: To answer @HenningMakholm's last question, you can visit https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I be admitted into the US again?

Yes.  There is an automatic ban if you accrue 180 days or more of "unlawful presence."  You have not reached that threshold.  But if you have been using the visa waiver program, you are probably ineligible to use it in the future.

> What can I do?

Apply for a B-2 visa.